# MySQL command ASCII

Tags: mysql, oracle

I am using Oracle iSQL *plus and while learning the `ASCII` command I encountered a doubt.

```
SELECT ASCII('A'),ASCII('a') FROM DUAL
```

prints the ASCII value of ('A') and ('a') respectively.

So how can we print the ASCII value of null because

```
SELECT ASCII('') FROM DUAL
```

prints nothing, but the ASCII value of null is 0.

Comment: `''` is not anything, it's a string that contains no characters, hence no ASCII characters. The ASCII `NUL` character is not the same as *no* character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL null is a state (unknown) and not a value. This usage is quite different from programming languages, where null means not assigned to a particular instance.

Source:- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)

So NULL cannot be represented in SQL

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try following:

select ASCII('\0') from dual

That will do you stuff.

Comment: No, it prints the ASCII value of '\'

Comment: select ASCII(CHR(0)) from dual?

Comment: I don't know how does the output comes 0 bt chr(0)  is not equal to NULL.

    `SELECT length(chr(0)) FROM dual;`

    `LENGTH(CHR(0))`


    =1

    `SELECT length(NULL) FROM dual;`

    LENGTH(NULL)

Comment: Null is not a character. It's "nothing".

Comment: Thats what I am saying 
    `SELECT LENGTH(CHR(0)) FROM DUAL;`
shows that the length is 1 but length of NUL should be 0, right?

Comment: The only what you can do is to use the isnull () function. Like isnull (null, chr (0)) = chr (0)

Comment: @amish You're confusing several things. The ASCII `NUL` character, byte value `0x0`, is **one character**. It's a regular character. A string with an ASCII `NUL` character in it is a string with one character in it. The SQL `NULL` value (note: not `NUL`) is something particular to SQL and has a special meaning in SQL, the meaning of "nothing".

Comment: @deceze The ASCII value of `NUL` is 0, and my only concern for now is how to print the ascii value of `NUL`.
By my knowledge I am assuming that `NUL` cannot be represented in SQL commands.